# Quiz App will not load after importing files

Tags: react-native, path

I am creating a simple quiz app as I am learning React Native.  I created a Folder to store all the components I will need.

[image]

However, I have this error:
[image]

Does anybody know why this error is coming up?  I am not sure why it has "data" in small caps since I have it in VS code as uppercase d.  This is a strange error I have never seen before.  Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I think could be happening:

1. In your Quiz.js file - You might have imported and tried to use a node module that is not installed
2. Even though your folder has a "D" for data - You might have had the path to it( at least in one file)  as a small cap
3. You could be calling referencing a path to a file that is completely outside the scope of your project.

I have never seen exactly this type of error before, but it looks similar to the ones I have seen when I have made mistakes like the ones I mentioned above.